# spl-token:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cdn, solana

I want import https://npm.devtool.tech/cdn/@solana/spl-token for my google extension

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/spl-token"></script>
```

Web3.js is working fine. But SPL-Token raise Exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at spl-token:12:23
```

I tried another CDNs, but all to no avail.

Comment: This is actually a bug, could you submit an issue explaining the issue with the browser build of spl-token at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues?

Comment: sounds like your webpack or babel config is messy. I would try to compare my tsconfig and nextjs.config.js to a scaffold like this github.com/thuglabs/create-dapp-solana-nextjs

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has this been resolved?